# How exactly does the [ClassName]... parameter work

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm working with Room in android development using java. For the Dao methods for inserts, the parameters I'm seeing online use a ClassName... className parameter. I think I'm understanding that this is some kind of array or collection, but how exactly does it work? What all does it apply to? Can you just drop a vector in there or do you have to do it like explicitly declaring an array?

Answer (score 1):

the three dots you saw in the docs is known as ellipsis and is used by Java to define varags! Varags or variable arguments is used when the parameter length is not known. You can pass as many parameters as you want that have the same type as defined in varags!

```
void add(int... numbers)
```

in the above example you can pass as many integers as you want, it is neither an array nor a vector as you mentioned! in the case of insert DAO in Room you can pass as many classes as you want!

Answer (score 0):

From the Class, that has been specified, Room generates the underlying code taking into consideration the Class's properties such as members/fields.

For example take the following Class which has the @Entity annotation and is therefore a Table.

```
@Entity(tableName = DataConstant.ORDER_TABLE)
data class Order(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "orderId")
    val id: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "status")
    var status: String
)
```

Which could have the following method/function in a class/interface that is annotated with @Dao:-

```
@Insert
abstract fun insert(order: Order): Long
```

In the generated Java in (for the Class annotated with @Dao, the name of the generated class being the class name suffixed with **_Impl**) it will include :-

```
private final EntityInsertionAdapter<Order> __insertionAdapterOfOrder;
```

and then :-

```
this.__insertionAdapterOfOrder = new EntityInsertionAdapter<Order>(__db) {
  @Override
  public String createQuery() {
    return "INSERT OR ABORT INTO `order_table` (`orderId`,`status`) VALUES (?,?)";
  }

  @Override
  public void bind(SupportSQLiteStatement stmt, Order value) {
    if (value.getId() == null) {
      stmt.bindNull(1);
    } else {
      stmt.bindString(1, value.getId());
    }
    if (value.getStatus() == null) {
      stmt.bindNull(2);
    } else {
      stmt.bindString(2, value.getStatus());
    }
  }
};
```

I.e. Room's annotation processing has ascertained that the Order class has 2 members/fields and that a table called **order_table** has been defined, via the tableName parameter/argument ( as per `const val ORDER_TABLE: String = "order_table"`).

So room has built the SQL to INSERT a row that takes 2 parameters that are bound (protects against SQL injection). Your code will effectively invoke generated function.

Finally Room generates, again in the generated java :-

```
  @Override
  public long insert(final Order order) {
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    __db.beginTransaction();
    try {
      long _result = __insertionAdapterOfOrder.insertAndReturnId(order);
      __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
      return _result;
    } finally {
      __db.endTransaction();
    }
  }
```

So for this insert a single **Order** is required to be passed.

If you coded, in the Dao class:-

```
@Insert
abstract fun insert( vararg order: Order)
```

Then the following Overidden Insert is generated (both the single and multiple inserts can exist together) :-

```
  @Override
  public void insert(final Order... order) {
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    __db.beginTransaction();
    try {
      __insertionAdapterOfOrder.insert(order);
      __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
      __db.endTransaction();
    }
  }
```